# "Expecting a description" error in systemverilog when instantiating a class

Tags: syntax, system-verilog

I think my Quartus is broken, but I'm hoping for a syntax error (the [semi-colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378042/verilog-error-expecting-a-description) look right). I stole this exact code from [here](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/classes/), and since it doesn't work I'm hoping somebody knows what to check in Quartus to get this to compile.

### Code:

```
class C;
  int x;
  task set (int i);
    x = i;
  endtask
  function int get;
    return x;
  endfunction
endclass
```

### Error:

[image: Picture of Error]

### Error text:

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at enable_logic_tb.sv(42) near text: "class";  expecting a description. Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
```

Answer (score 2):

Quartus does not synthesize classes. The `class` construct is only for simulation.

Comment: So cryptic... You're saying that Quartus can't support that language feature? Further that classes or Quartus are only for simulation?

Comment: The tool you are using does not even understand `class` is a keyword, so it cannot tel you the code you are writing is unsupported.

Comment: Please define the "it" which starts the second sentence of your answer.

Comment: Is there a list of (un)supported features for Quartus?

Comment: The tool you appear to be running: _Quartus Prime analysis and synthesis_. See http://quartushelp.altera.com/current/index.htm#hdl/vlog/vlog_list_sys_vlog.htm

Comment: I meant to say the `class` construct is only supported for simulation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158555/discussion-between-user121330-and-dave-59).